# VSCODE gopath different from GOPATH set in shell

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am encountering a very weird issue on visual studio code when i try to import packages.

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

I get the error

```
cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
        /user/chirrut/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

however when i run go build from the terminal, I don't get any error.
also note that the GOPATH is set to /home/chirrut/go instead of /user/chirrut/go
I ran echo on terminal, and the vscode integrated terminal and both returns me the correct path.

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/chirrut/go
```

Somehow, somewhere VSCode is getting the GOPATH value as /user/chirrut/go instead. anyone have any idea where else is the GOPATH variable read from in VS Code?

Comment: If you changed path after starting `code`,  then try restarting, If not see `File>Preferences>Settings` and search for `go.infer` and see if you need to make any changes there.

Comment: well, i did not make any change in the path cause i leave it as default.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with the ms-vscode.go plugin, if I disable it, the problem go away. and if i enable it, it comes back. Strangely I tried uninstalling it completely, and then reinstall it again, and the problem goes away.

Note: No, I did not make any changes to GOPATH at all since i first setup golang.